# Google datastore modelling

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am designing a data structure to be stored in Google Datastore.

1. Applications have categories
2. Categories have other properties

I like to query All Applications belonging to a particular category
I also like to get a sum total of the number of applications in a given category.

To achieve this i have designed the following classes.

**application.py**

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
from cfc.models.admin.applicationcategory import ApplicationCategory

class Application(ndb.model):
    """ Application Model"""
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    category = ApplicationCategory()
```

**applicationcategory.py**

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

class ApplicationCategory(ndb.model):
    """Models an application Category"""
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    date_created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

My questions are how does one define the queries given that, datastore is eventually consistent ?

Comment: read about using parents re:eventual consistency. other than that this question lacks a lot of info to give you advice.

Answer (score 1):

Datastore is not optimized for this type of scenario. The best option to get the count of application based on a given category is to use the [search api](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/faceted_search). Create a document for each application and add category as a facet. Then you can use faceted search to get the count using facet value query.